# How to use spring data jpa to access keycloak DB

Tags: jpa, keycloak

I am keycloak freshman and using keycloak to controll access authority in my project now.
But when i called some restAPIs whitch provided by keycloak itself,i found some APIs can not meet our requirement.For example,i would query users info by id list.
but keycloak only provided api to query all users.

So,i think can i use jpa to access DB of keycloak directly?

But i searched many info from network but found nothings,is there someone would give me some help or example.

Thanks.

Comment: Is "keycloakdb" an RDBMS? If not then JPA is not the tool for you ...

Comment: Yes.i mean that, i set  my keycloak inclued database to MYSQL,so i though how can i use jpa to query datas of keycloak directly from MYSQL.

Comment: Tell people where are your ENTITIES that map on to those tables ? You would get all of this by reading BASIC JPA documentation ...

Answer (score 0):

You can query a user by id using this REST endpoint

```
{baseUrl}/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{userId}
```

You can query Keycloak database using JDBC or Hibernate (a JPA provider). You just need to connect to the database as to a usual database, using an URL like this:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloak`

And map necessary data to entity classes. For example, for a users table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_entity")
class User {

  @Column(name = "ID")
  private String id;  

  @Column(name = "USERNAME")
  private String userName;

}
```